# Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I want to upgrade from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019. Does anyone know a method to not lose my projects and settings?

Comment: As with previous versions, they install side by side.  See [Install Visual Studio versions side-by-side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019) and [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: The list of recent projects is shared between 2017 and 2019. Any options not imported automatically can be exported & imported manually. Extensions need to be done manually (but the Extension Manager extension can automate that.)

Comment: You can't upgrade visual studio 2017 IDE to Visual Studio 2019 IDE. However you can run both IDE's in parallel. You can directly open your project in Visual Studio 2019 and it will automatically upgrade the things it required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't lose any files. your projects are saved on your computer not on a VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

When you go and upgrade to Visual Studio 2019, you won't lose your files, it does it all for you.